# how to implement validation for name and year of birth

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jpa

I have the jsp page with html form which has two textfields for a name, year of birth and a search button, for searching a user/s. A user has the option to search by entering both name and year of birth or by name or by year of birth, which means he can leave one textfield empty and enter name and vice-versa. So the result in a table, if we enter for example just year of birth, should show all the users with that year of birth.

I have generated an entity class from a database table, which looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE v.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE v.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByYearBirth", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE v.yearBirth= :yearBirth"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByNameYearBirth", 
            query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name or p.yearBirth = :yearBirth")})
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "yearBirth")
    private Short yearBirth;

    // constructors, setters, getters...
}
```

ControllerServlet class:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = request.getServletPath();

    if (path.equals("/index")) {
    }
    else if (path.equals("/search_users")) {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String yearBirth= request.getParameter("yearBirth");

        Query findByNameYearBirth = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByNameYearBirth");
        findByNameYearBirth.setParameter("name", name);
        findByNameYearBirth.setParameter("yearBirth", Short.parseShort(yearBirth));
        List persons = findByNameYearBirth.getResultList();
        request.setAttribute("findByNameYearBirth", persons);
    }
    else if (path.equals("/add_person")) {
    }
    else if (path.equals("/delete_person")) {
    }
    String url = path + ".jsp";
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

Inside doPost method of the ControllerServlet class, for a path "/search_users", with a following code I can search and get result for a person/s if i enter name and year of birth, or if I just enter year. 
So If I enter a name and leave yearBirth textfield blank, I get an exception: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

According to the scenario above and this exception, how should I implement validation?

Comment: can't you use different named query just for findByName and invoke it if you receive blank yearOfBirth?

Comment: problem is, im not sure what type of the conditions i should do? should i go for condition if (yearOfBirth == null) or condition like (yearOfBirth.isEmpty())..

Comment: @Xerath Updated my post. You can optimize the conditions as your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception occurs at `Short.parseShort()` when `yearBrith` is empty String.

```
findByNameYearBirth.setParameter("yearBirth", Short.parseShort(yearBirth));
```

You should check them null or empty first before setting as query parameter.

In this case using `Dynamic query` is suitable instead of `NamedQuery` usage. You should prepare dynamic query based on `name` and `yearBirth` value.

---

Dynamic query can be done by `em.createQuery()`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT p FROM Person p");

if (<name or yearBirth is not null and empty>)
    sb.append(" WHERE");
if (<name is not null and not empty>) {
    sb.append(" p.name = :name");
    if (<yearBirth is not null and not empty>)
        sb.append(" AND");
}
if (<yearBirth is not null and not empty>)
    sb.append(" p.yearBirth = :yearBirth");

//then create query
Query query = em.createQuery(sb.toString());

//then set query param
if (<name is not null and not empty>)
    query.setParameter("name", name);
if (<yearBirth is not null and not empty>)
    query.setParameter("yearBirth", Short.parseShort(yearBirth));

//Now your query is ready to use
```

Comment: I'll write UPDATE, so you can check my order of what I think validation should look like. By the way, how do you use Dynamic query ?

Comment: This looks nice I'll test it in a few minutes. However, do I need a tryCatch for NumberFormatException for yearBirth ?

Comment: Ok, just give me a moment, and I will accept your answer if I don't have some more questions, i need to check something.. ;)

Comment: So the problem now is, if I enter yearBirth and leave name blank, I get an sql exception because we don't have left part of AND condition, so the statement looks like: SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE AND p.yearBirth = :yearBirth

Comment: which also means, in case if we leave both textfield blank, sql statement will look like SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE, is there other way to do this validation ? :/

Comment: @Xerath Good point, yes, you must handle that situation by checking `name` and `yearBirth` value again. Will you try please? :)

Comment: Sorry, for late response, I was afk. Yes, if (<yearBirth is not null and not empty>) that's the way I would go too. However, now when I reminded on how to use null & isEmpty, I think I got an idea on how to to implement validation another way. Is it possible again with @NamedQuery ? It might be a long code. What do you think ?

Comment: @Xerath Yes, you can use `NamedQuery` and setting param according to condition.

Answer (score 0):

4 digit year use regex

for four digit year on the java side

```
String yearBirth= request.getParameter("yearBirth");
String pattern = "^\d{4}";
if(yearBirth.matches("^\d{4}")) {
    // matches!
} else {
    // doesn't matches
}
```

Comment: Thank for sharing that info, but I'm not using Date type, so I don't have to use regex.

Comment: well okay :) you can also force validation in your entity with @Pattern annotation.